# Does searching using NSPredicate works on multiple language automatically?

Tags: objective-c

I want to know how searching of a string works in objective C when the iphone application has to support multiple language.

Assuming I have a search function that looks like this currently:

```
- (int)showSearchResultForQuery:(NSString *)query
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@ ||  address CONTAINS[cd] %@",query, query]; 
    storesFiltered = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[stores filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];    
    int count = [storesFiltered count];
    if(count > 0)
    {
        // we have some results          
        [resultTable reloadData];        
    }       
    return count;
}
```

This piece of code basically accepts a query string and update an array being used by a table using NSPredicate. I want to know, what do i need to take in consideration, if this function has to accepts multiple languages? chinese. english...japanese... will this function still work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you need to consider is that the encoding of the strings in the array will be the same as the encoding of the query string.

For example, chinese is sometimes represented in UTF16, so you need to make sure that both the strings in the array and query string are encoded in UTF16.

Everything else will work out of the box.